# Calculating the percentage of a plane that is underneath a slope

Tags: algorithm

I am a bit stuck with this problem.  I have an NxN square and a line that passes through this square.  How can I calculate the percentage of the NxN square that falls above and beneath the line given an arbitrary slope?  I imagine I have to use the Pythagorean theorem on this one, I am just not sure how to apply it.  Any help is appreciated. (Not homework)

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea: find the 0, 1 or 2 points where the line intersects the square. If there are 0 or 1 intersections, the square is entirely on one side of the line. If there are two, the square is bisected into two polygons (a triangle and a pentagon if the two intersections are on adjacent sides, or two quadrilaterals if the intersections are on opposite sides). Find the respective area of the two parts, and that will give you the percentages.

Comment: You could also have an infinite number of intersections (i.e., a side of the square could lie on the line).